# Clone div and alter style by onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone, box, maximize

In my HTML I have got 4 boxes that I want to increase in size and appear in the middle of the website by onclick. But it doesn't work with this clone version.

```js
function changeSize(id, weight, height){
 //$( "." + id ).clone().appendTo( "new" + id );
 var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    clone = elem.cloneNode(true); // true means clone all childNodes and all event handlers
 clone.id = "newid" +id;
 document.body.appendChild(clone);
     
    
    if(elem.getAttribute('style')){
        elem.removeAttribute('style');
    } else {
        elem.style.width = weight + 'px';
        elem.style.height = height + 'px';
        elem.style.fontSize = '30px';
       
        elem.style.position = 'absolute';
        elem.style.left= '40%';
    }
}

var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('kaesten');
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
    elems[i].onclick = function(){
        changeSize(this.id, 600, 600);
    }
}
```

```css
.kaesten{
 width:240px;
 height:300px;
 background-color:darkgrey;
 background-position:center;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 text-shadow:0px 0px 3px #000;
 border: 5px solid #F0F8ff;
 vertical-align:top;
 text-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #777;
 float:left;
 margin-left:30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1" class="kaesten">test1</div>
<div id="box2" class="kaesten">test2</div>
<div id="box3" class="kaesten">test3</div>
<div id="box4" class="kaesten">test4</div>
```

Question: How can I clone the box by onclick and show it in the middle of the site? How can I remove it by onclick?

Comment: To clone: you must replicate the state of the object, that can be done by enumerating and copying its properties or by creating the objects from a 'blueprint' of sorts. To move it to the middle of the site, modify its CSS attributes, namely TOP and LEFT , and to remove it by onclick simply add an event listener and remove it from its parent within the DOM

Comment: You need the code in pure javascript or jquery can be used ?

Comment: @nolags: Are you looking for something like this - https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/0tx5do9w/ ?

Comment: @nitish koundade: jqeuery can be used too.

Comment: @Abhitalks: the #overlayContent{ height: calc(..); the calc function doesn't work. And implemented in my site the boxes don't close.

Comment: @nolags: When you say `calc` doesn't work, what does that mean? Are you using IE<=8? Then it won't work. Otherwise all browsers support it. Secondly, if the boxes aren't closing in your site then it means you are missing something and not copying my code as is.

Comment: @Abhitalks calc(100%-24px) is underlined red! I use IE11. I checked the code nothing is missing.

Comment: @nolags: As per the specs -- [*..whitespace is required on both sides of the `+` and `-` operators..*](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc-syntax)

Answer (score 1):

You can modify CSS with jQuery css() Method :
source : http://api.jquery.com/css/

To set a specified CSS property, use the following syntax:

> css("propertyname","value");

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.kaesten').click(function() {
    $('.kaesten').removeAttr('style');
    
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#' + id).css({
      "width": "30em",
      "height": "18em",
      "top": "50%",
      "left": "50%",
      "position": "fixed",
      "margin-top": "-9em",
      "margin-left": "-15em",
      "background-color": "blue"

    });

  });
});
```

```css
.kaesten {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 240px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #000;
  border: 5px solid #F0F8ff;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #777;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'helvetica';
}
.container {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="box1" class="kaesten">test1</div>
  <div id="box2" class="kaesten">test2</div>
  <div id="box3" class="kaesten">test3</div>
  <div id="box4" class="kaesten">test4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you don't understand the question, a comment is more appropriate than a stab at rep-gathering

Comment: Sorry, i have modified my answer.

Comment: No need to apologize to me, I don't have personal feelings toward your answer regardless..I was just letting you know since you originally indicated that you didn't understand the question and I'm not sure how modifying your answer will change that

Comment: Yes, you were right, my comment about the question was not necessary. I have modified my answer in order to do the effect asked : "…boxes that I want to increase in size and appear in the middle of the website by onclick". User can comment my answer now if if he wants to give more infos.

Comment: That's not exactly what I wanted: I don't want the original box to move from its place I want to clone it and show it in the middle of the side.

Comment: @nolags I don’t see exactly what you mean. Could you update your question with a screenshot or wireframe of the desired effect ? I will update my code then.

Comment: @SébastienGicquel I want the boxes 1 to 4 to stay on their place, and show a clone in bigger size in the middle of the site, to make something like a zoom function and not change the original boxes!

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to bring the div in middle and on clicking it should go back to the original position .Try this code , no jquery required.

```js
function changeSize(id, weight, height){
 var elem = document.getElementById(id); 
 if(elem.className == 'absoluteclass'){
    elem.setAttribute('class','kaesten');
 }else{         
  var currentAbsoluteElem =   document.getElementsByClassName('absoluteclass');
  if(currentAbsoluteElem.length > 0){
  console.log(currentAbsoluteElem[0])
  currentAbsoluteElem[0].setAttribute('class','kaesten');
  } 
   var elem = document.getElementById(id);
   elem.setAttribute('class','absoluteclass');
 /* for making the height , width dynamic you can change it from here
           elem.style.width = weight + 'px';
           elem.style.height = height + 'px';
           elem.style.left= '40%'; 
 */
 }
}

var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('kaesten');
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
    elems[i].onclick = function(){
        changeSize(this.id, 600, 600);
    }
}
```

```css
.kaesten{
 width:240px;
 height:300px;
 background-color:darkgrey;
 background-position:center;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 text-shadow:0px 0px 3px #000;
 border: 5px solid #F0F8ff;
 vertical-align:top;
 text-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #777;
 float:left;
 margin-left:30px;
}
.absoluteclass{
   position:absolute;
   background-color:darkgrey;
   width:600px;
   height:600px;
   left:calc(50% - 300px);
   
}
```

```html
<div id="box1" class="kaesten">test1</div>
<div id="box2" class="kaesten">test2</div>
<div id="box3" class="kaesten">test3</div>
<div id="box4" class="kaesten">test4</div>
```

No Need to clone the div , If still you need to clone the div we might need to change the code accordingly.You can check the  JSFIDDLE [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nitish1604/rkh1fs5q/)

Comment: The place of the onlicked box can be empty but I don't think it looks good when the other boxes fill the place.

Answer (score 0):

Updated Code : Hope this is what you were looking for :)

```js
function changeSize(id, weight, height){
     var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    var currentAbsoluteElem = document.getElementById('dummy');
     var text = elem.innerHTML;
     currentAbsoluteElem.innerHTML = text;
    currentAbsoluteElem.style="display:block";
     /*Extra styling neeed  to be done here*/
     
 }

var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('kaesten');
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
    elems[i].onclick = function(){
        changeSize(this.id, 600, 600);
    }
}

var absoluteCl = document.getElementsByClassName('absoluteclass');
absoluteCl[0].onclick = function(){
        console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('absoluteclass'))
        document.getElementsByClassName('absoluteclass')[0].setAttribute('style','display:none');
}
```

```css
.kaesten{
 width:240px;
 height:300px;
 background-color:darkgrey;
 background-position:center;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 text-shadow:0px 0px 3px #000;
 border: 5px solid #F0F8ff;
 vertical-align:top;
 text-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #777;
 float:left;
 margin-left:30px;
}
.absoluteclass{
   position:absolute;
   background-color:darkgrey;
   width:600px;
   height:600px;
   left:calc(50% - 300px);
   display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1" class="kaesten">test1</div>
<div id="box2" class="kaesten">test2</div>
<div id="box3" class="kaesten">test3</div>
<div id="box4" class="kaesten">test4</div>
<div id="dummy" class="absoluteclass"></div>
```

Comment: Its working in the above demo itself , click any box a new box popups . are you asking for any other click event ??

Comment: when I use your demo and click on a box there doesn't happen anything! What I wanted was to click on a box and this box pops up in the middle of the page with increased size and font size. The other boxes should rest on their place and not move.

Comment: Yes thats what exactly the updated code do.I have just run the code snippet here itself. only the thing is that i have not increased the font size.can i get the link where your are using the code or a jsfiddle of your code??

Comment: have you checked that i have added a extra div with id dummy. might be this is missing in your code.

Comment: yes I have and it is exactly what I need :) but it doesn't work:  https://jsfiddle.net/r6ebstt6/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100365/discussion-between-nitish-koundade-and-nolags).

Comment: Issue was in the chrome , in firefox its working fine.For this code to work in chrome
Change the line in the function changeSize from

currentAbsoluteElem.style="display:block";

to the line below

currentAbsoluteElem.setAttribute('style','display:block');